# Current Datetime in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I can't just make this work.

How can i display the current date in PHP in the format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.

Regards

Matt

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
echo date('YmdHis');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`date`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
echo date("YmdHis");
```

That'll display the current date in the format you asked for in the timezone of whatever machine PHP is running on.